# Animated Themes for Windows XP

Tags: windows, animation, windows-xp, themes, skinning

How do I create an animated theme for windows XP? I know how to create normal themes, but can't seem to find anythoing on adding animation.

This is what I need:

The Start menu should be themed like an iPhone, so I slide to lock/unlock the start menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know if this is possible. You might be able to use some of [Stardock's](http://www.stardock.com/products/)
products to cobble something together...